# Conflicting Wine package

Tags: package-management, wine, mono

i need to install wine for Photoshop, and i just use ubuntu for 2 weeks, so i follow this guide [Building Biarch Wine On Ubuntu](https://wiki.winehq.org/Building_Biarch_Wine_On_Ubuntu) to do that. But there are something i dont understand in this guide, although i have installed it successful:

> Warning: When you **install a locally built version of Wine**, the package
>   management system will not know it exists since it did not come from a
>   package. Thus it is possible to later **break its dependencies or
>   install a conflicting version of Wine** without a warning from the
>   package management tools. You can prevent this by **creating a package**
>   or by **blocking conflicting packages with apt-pinning by setting
>   "Pin-Priority: -1" for the packages.**
>
> Next, install Mono, Gecko, and optionally winetricks **if you had to
>   remove their packages because of a dependency on a conflicting Wine
>   package**.
>
> And you're done! Use wine --version to check the version installed.

Can someone explain to me about the bold sentences. And what exactly i have to do to prevent conflicting version of Wine?

and when i use wine --version to check the version i get this error

> bash: /usr/local/bin/wine: No such file or directory

Do i need to install Mono, Gecko to use that command?

After all, i apologize for my english because it is really bad, and thanks for reading.

Comment: You do not need gecko or mono here. The error you posted means that the wine executable is not in /usr/local/bin/wine.  Doesn't the guide say that you install wine in /home/$user/wine32/ .. .

Comment: but when i use 'type -a wine', i get 'wine is /usr/local/bin/wine', what does this mean? and yes, i install wine in /home/$user/wine32/.., so what should i do in this case?

Comment: This means that you use the wine program from the /usr/local/bin/ . I think you want to start it from $home/wine32/.. . You can do this with running the executable manually $home/wine32/bin/wine ?? or similar.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to go ahead with GUI installation.

First you need to remove wine completely. Below are the commands for the same.

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove wine
```

After deleting the files run command:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge wine
```

Do the following to correct any installation error.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

**Installation steps:**

Click on Ubuntu Software >> Search (Configure Wine)
Click Install.